# Python - Get last logon from exchange

Tags: python, exchange-server

I would like to retrieve the last logon time from a defined user in python.

This is the equivalent in powershell :

```
$mbx = Get-Mailbox billgates |Get-MailboxStatistics
$mbx.LastLogonTime
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this part of the Exchange API isn't exposed via EWS. So you aren't able to fetch it directly from python with libarys like exchangelib. Alternativ approaches may be to update the information periodically via powershell and expose it with an interchange format like csv or json to your python code. Or open a remote powershell thru python or use a library like stateful-process-command-proxy to expose the cmdlet via restfull api. The security on this apporach is up to you.